# Freeze Column headers in IE 6.0 and IE 7.0

Tags: html, css

This is the code sample of a simple list display with a scroll button..It is working good. But now i want to freeze first row..that is the header..Can you please help me..

```
<div id="user">
        <table class="user_list" frame="box" bordercolor="#c1a3cf"
                       border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
           <thead>
             <tr>
                <th  style="padding-top:15px;"> Nr. </th>
                <th  style="padding-top:15px;"> Concession Nr. </th>
                <th  style="padding-top:15px;"> Action Performed </th>
                <th  style="padding-top:15px;"> Action by </th>
                <th  style="padding-top:15px;"> Action on </th>
             </tr>
             </thead>
           <tbody>
              <?php  $result = get_user_actionlog($seite,$entries);

              if($seite == 1) {
                 $number = 0;
              } else {
                 $number = ($seite-1) * $entries;
              }

            while($record = odbc_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td width="25" class="rtodata"><?php $number += 1;
                      echo $number;?></td>
             <td width="150" class="rtodata"><?php echo $record['concession']; ?>  </td>
             <td width="400" class="rtodata"><?php  echo $record['action_performed'];?></td>
             <td width="75" class="rtodata"><?php echo $record['action_by'];?></td>
             <td width="100" class="rtodata"><?php echo $record['action_on'];?></td>
           </tr>
            <?php }?>
         </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
```

and in my CSS file,

```
#user {width: 900px;height:800px;overflow:auto;}
```

**EDIT:-**

[scrollable table with fixed header](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) works perfectly in IE 6.0 nad in Firefox but not in IE 7.0. If any of you champs can update that...

Comment: What do you mean by "Freeze?"

Comment: I mean to say eventhough i scroll down using scroll bar, the headers should be fixed. I should be able to see headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the table with divs with outer and then innera..check the css

```
.outer {
    position:relative;
    padding:4em 0 3em 0;
    width:54em;
    background:bottom;
    margin:0 auto 3em auto;
}
.innera {
    overflow:auto;
    width:54em;
    height:9.6em;
    background:#eee;
    border:2px gray;
}
.outer thead tr {
    position:absolute;
    top:2em;
    height:1.5em;
    left:0;

}
.outer th, .outer td {
    width:10em;
    text-align:left;
```

I tested the code and it is working. Tested in IE 6.0,7.0 ++ .The code is from internet:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a class to the `<thead>` and using `position: fixed;` You'll need to add some padding to your div to make it display as you wish.

[Example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/d7Prv/).

---

IE isn't good at supporting <strike>anything</strike> scrolling tables. Editing a table in this way is rarely a good idea in any case. You can have one table with your TH wrapped in a div, then the rest of your info in another table, with another div with overflow auto

[Another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/d7Prv/1/).

It's not perfect as you have a lot on HTML visual attributes, you should get rid of those and use CSS only. But this is the basic functionality, it should work in all browsers.

Comment: +1, Thanku for the reply. But i have tried your example, the column headers are not fixed. can you please check again.

Comment: See example, the headers are very much fixed :) Which browser are you using? I teste in Chrome, FF and IE8.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write about browser..i checked in IE 7.0. Header is not fixed. In mozilla 3.6.13 headers are fixed...But on scrolling down, the data is flowing over the header information. Can you please find a work around for IE 6.0 and IE 7.0

Comment: gud work around...but with 2 tables...Please post if you can know the trick with single table:-)

Comment: The only way around it is my first example, if you add a background color to the `<thead>` it won't look as if though it's "flowing over" the content :)